# JobRunr - Trying to run multiple recurring jobs with Spring Boot

Tags: background-process, recurring, jobrunr

I am using JobRunr to run my background jobs and in this I am providing the users to setup recurring jobs using an endpoint like below:

```
@PostMapping("/schedule-recurring")
    public String scheduleRecurring(@RequestBody ExecutionJob executionJob) {
        return BackgroundJob.scheduleRecurrently(executionJob.getId(),executionJob.getCronExpression(), ()
                -> jobService.executeSomeJob(executionJob, JobContext.Null));
    }
```

These jobs could run in 5 mins, 10 mins or it might sometimes take upto 4 hours. This all depends on how many records to process. Right now, I am in a phase where I have only one background job server since I am building a POC for this. However, in future we plan to scale it to support 1 instance per customer having one or multiple background job server based on the client license.

My issue here is that, I have 2 recurring jobs which run 1 hour apart from each other. The first recurring job executes for more than 1 hour and deems the second job unexecuted, because this job is not triggered as there is no available Background Job Worker to address this request. I am thinking of adding a check to the job to trigger itself only if a Background Job Worker is available. But is there a better idea where-in the schedule-recurring method itself adds a condition to queue the job if a Background Job worker is not available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the problem completely - if no worker is available, the job will just stay enqueued and the moment a worker is available, the job will be processed. JobRunr also makes sure that recurring jobs are not run in parallel (e.g. if your recurring cron job is every 5 minutes but your job takes 10 minutes to finish, it will only enqueue a new job when the previous job is finished). Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's the tricky part. JobRunr allows you to run recurring cron job if at the time of job to run, it has a free agent. If not, then the run is skipped.

Comment: The run is not skipped but delayed. If you go for the Pro version, you have priorities that make sure your recurring job always run on time.

Comment: Ok... But my question was more on why it is not queued? Or how can I queue it if a worker is not available.

Comment: The recurring job will be queued. It will only be skipped if the same recurring job is still running (reason for this: if a job is taking 15 mins and you schedule it every 5 minutes, you will create more jobs than you can process.). I hope this answers your question?